# How to configure qmake so my app is install with "make install"?

Tags: qt, makefile, installation, qmake

I have a written a small qt app that I use qmake to build, but I am missing the make install target.
How to configure qmake so my binary is copied to /usr/local/bin/ when I run "make install"?

1. qmake
2. make
3. make install

What do I need to add to my .pro file to get the "install" target and how do I control what file and path will be used?

---

Btw the install will be on Linux pc:s like Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: What does the "without any success" stand for?

Answer (score 14):

Add something like this to you .pro file

```
target.path = /usr/local/bin/
INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: I first read it as to your .profile. Crucial space. It obvious that it shall go into .pro.